# Would a 'static const rvalue' make sense?

Tags: c++, static, constants, rvalue

Given a class that defines an event and has a costly constructor (in my case, it computes a hashe of the event name so that I can later perform comparisons against an int instead of the event name string), I found that the way to go in order not to repeat the construction operation is to have a static const declaration, so it gets constructed the first time and reused again and again.

Let us say the constructor of the event class is this:

```
Event(const char *name);
```

And I have a function to send events like this one:

```
send(const Event &e);
```

I would like to send an event in a way similar to the following:

```
// For instance
send("myevent");
...
// Or even
send(Event("myevent"));
```

But that of course calls the Event constructor every time the event is send. The first solution I came up with is to declare a static const before the call:

```
static const Event myevent("myevent");
send(myevent);
```

That's not too bad, but in order to convert this construct into a one-line statement I can use the preprocessor:

```
// Preprocessor macro
#define SEND(event_name) \
             { static const Event myevent(event_name); \
               send(myevent); }
...
// And then later
SEND("myevent");
```

Although I would prefer not using the preprocessor if possible. That could be done if I could tell the compiler I want an rvalue like the Event instance in this case to be static const, which I don't know if possible... does it make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it good enough to just make an `Event` cache, and look it up by name at runtime (creating if necessary)?

Comment: If your parameter was something that could be a compile time constant, you could make a class `template< type X > struct cached_event;` which holds a `static const Event` and is convertible to it. Maybe you can manage something similar with string literals?

Comment: Is `"myevent"` representative of a type or just label?